# How to prove in any $△ABC$ that if $∠B$ is acute, then $c > b \cdot \cos A$?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In any $△ABC$, (where side $a$ is opposite to $∠A$, side $b$ is opposite to $∠B$ and side $c$ is opposite to$∠C$. Why is it if $∠B$ is acute, then $c > b \cdot \cos A$ (as shown in the image below)? I feel like it has something to do with the cosine rule but have no idea how to show it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to show
$$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}<\frac cb$$
This happens iff
\begin{align}
&{b^2+c^2-a^2}<2c^2\\
\iff &c^2+a^2-b^2>0\\
\iff &\cos B>0
\end{align}
Hence Proved.

Comment: From what you've given, I tried taking the arccosine of both sides and got
$B>90°$
which don't seem to be correct because cosine's value decreases if $B>90°$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali, Which both sides are you talking about? In the last step $\cos B>0$ means $B\in(0,90^\circ)$ (because $\cos B$ takes negative values for $B\in(90^\circ,180^\circ)$).

Comment: so I believe I can't do cos$^{-1}$(cos $B$) > cos$^{-1}0$ to get $B > 90°$ (which seems quite wrong too)?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali, Yeah you can't do that.

Comment: I know that I can't do that, but I don't really understand why I can't. My steps seems correct. I'd appreciate if you can explain where did I go wrong and why it's wrong.

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali, Because [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5oDQ.png) is the graph of $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x))$, it's neither increasing nor decreasing, so we can't do such things. $\cos$ is actually not an invertible function, we restrict its domain to invert it. such graphs are also easy to be seen with other periodic functions like $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\angle B$ is acute, $c>b$. 
Since $-1≤\cos A≤1$ that means that $c>b\cos A$.
When $\angle B$ is obtuse, $b$ is the longest side, then same logic

Comment: Why do you think that $c>b$ when $\angle B$ is acute. $\angle C$ may be even lesser.